# What does change column mean in Stack Overflow Top user rankings?

Tags: discussion, top-users

In the top user section, there is one column (I highlighted it in the image below), **change**. What does that mean?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number of positions you changed since your last ranking.

If you were rank **#1000** last month and rank **#100** this month the change column would say **+900**.